# ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

Tags: asp.net

Buen dia a todos, al momento de descargar un pdf y agregarle una "," (comma) al header del pdf me marca el error:

> ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

Pueden guiarme como puedo solucionar esto?, necesito que el nombre del pdf tenga sea asi: "Ejemplo, Revision.Pdf"

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
Dim nameFinal As String = "Ejemplo, Revision.pdf"     
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & nameFinal)
```

Uso vb.net, y esto solo pasa en Chrome, en IE funciona bien

Comment: .. o simplemente no pongas coma en el nombre del archivo. Usa "-" o "_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo al [estándar HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2), debes encerrar el nombre del archivo en comillas dobles. Si el nombre lleva, a su vez, comillas, utilizas la *barra invertida* `\` como secuencia de escape.

El navegador debe ver algo como esto:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mi archivo con, coma.txt"
```

Por tanto, tu código debiera ser algo como:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" & nameFinal & "\"")
```

Comment: Hermano, mil gracias, a mi me funcionó a la perfección!